# Count multiple columns with same WHERE condition

Tags: mysql, sql, count, multiple-columns

I have a users table with columns: `user_id, teacher_id1, teacher_id2, teacher_id3`

and

teachers table with id

Each user can have the same id's for `teacher_id1, teacher_id2, teacher_id3`

I would like to count how many users have same teacher.

User table

```
+----------------------------------------+
| user_Id teacher_id1 teacher_id2 teacher_id3 |
+----------------------------------------+
| 1        1           1           1     |
| 2        2           1           3     |
| 3        2           3           3     |
| 4        2           2           2     |
+----------------------------------------+
```

Teacher table

```
+------+
| id   |
+------+
| 1    |
| 2    |
| 3    |
```

Count for $id1 is: 2

Count for $id2 is: 3

Count for $id3 is: 2

I tried something like this, but it is not correct!

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE concat_ws('',teacher_id1 OR teacher_id2
OR teacher_id3) like '{$id}' ";
```

Comment: I don't understand your results vs the question.  Teacher_ID3 seems to have 3 different users (1, 3(twice), 2).  Why are you only expecting 1?  I guess I don't understand the numbers under the teacherIDs  why does teacher_ID1 and user_ID 1 have a value of 1 whereas user_ID 3 teacher_ID2 have a value of 3?

Comment: There is still the problem that nobody knows WHAT exactly you count

Comment: Count for $id3 shouldn't be 2 ???

Comment: I hope it is now more clearly...I have two tables: one is for teachers and other is for users...Each user can have three teachers with same id's..so I would like to count how many users have the same teacher but if user has all three teachers with same Id, count for that teacher is only one.

Comment: Meherzad - yes...my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query

```
select b.id, count(*) 
from
tbl1 a
inner join 
tbl2 b
on b.id = teacher_id1 or b.id = teacher_id2 or b.id = teacher_id3
group by b.id
```

### **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fd8fc/2)**:

```
| ID | COUNT(*) |
-----------------
|  1 |        2 |
|  2 |        3 |
|  3 |        2 |
```

Comment: Instead of b.id I used '{$id}' from which I get teacher id..but it does not working. I am new to mysql so I dont't know how to include '{$id}' in this code, which seems correct to me..

If I have only one column teacher_id1 

it works perfect with this code

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE teacher_id1 = '{$id}'` 

but if I have all three teacher_id1, teacher_id2, tecaher_id3 I don't know how to get it work :/

Comment: If you want the count for a specific teacher then you have to just add  a condition in the where clause like `WHERE b.id = {$id}`...  Hope it helps..

Comment: still no correct results :/ I tried to add `WHERE b.id = {$id}`

Comment: :P Can you please post the whole query that you are using ??

Comment: `public static function count_serviserji_uporabniki($id){
  global $database; 
  $sql = "SELECT b.id, count(*) FROM users a INNER JOIN teacher b on b.id = teacher_id1 or b.id = teacher_id2 or b.id = teacher_id3 WHERE b.id = '{$id}' group by b.id";
  $result_set = $database->query($sql);
  $row = $database->fetch_array($result_set);
  return array_shift($row);
 }`

Comment: To display count I use: `<?php echo Teacher::count_serviserji_uporabniki($teacher_data->id); ?>`

Comment: when I had only one column (teacher_id1) I used this code and it worked fine `public static function count_serviserji_uporabniki($id){
  global $database; 
  $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE teacher_id1 = '{$id}' ";
  $result_set = $database->query($sql);
  $row = $database->fetch_array($result_set);
  return array_shift($row);
 }`

Comment: Your query looks perfect..  so you are getting  wrong results ?? can you explain such scenario..\

Comment: instead of count, my result is id of a teacher..I don't get it =)

Comment: Ok got your problem... just change this in starting  `select count(*), b.id .....` then as it ....

Comment: Your retrieval code is wrong the query is giving correct result.. Hope this solves your problem...

Comment: Thank you very much! It is working now! I would buy you a beer if you were near hehe ;) thank you again...

Comment: Welcome man...  glad to help...  Coming for Beer ..  ;) ... Anyways your data retrieval code is not perfect please work on it.  I'm not a php guy so can't comment much...

Answer (score 1):

You have data in three different columns.  You need to combine it into one column, to get the distinct counts that you want.  For this, you can use `union all`.  Then the count is simply `count(distinct)`:

```
select teacher_id, COUNT(distinct USER_ID)
from ((select user_id, teacher_id1 as teacher_id
       from t
      ) union all
      (select user_id, teacher_id2
       from t
      ) union all
      (select user_id, teacher_id3
       from t
      )
     ) s
group by teacher_id;
```